# How does IDE show method parameter names?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jar, ide

I am writing a java program with an open source library using Eclipse and I am observing my IDE suggestions as follows. I added the library to my project by importing jar from IDE.

[image]

As you can see in the image, it shows me parameter names as srg0, arg1,..

However, in the source code of the library in github, it uses different variable names such as P, N, r.

I have observed in some cases IDE shows the same name that is used in the source.

I am curious on how IDE shows parameter name in such cases. How does the IDE pick parameter names to show here?

Comment: The parameter names can be trimmed out of the distribution jar. If they are, then the IDE just arbitrarily numbers them.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Either the references class would have had to be compiled using the -parameter compiler flag (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html)
Or you need to attach the source of the library to the library jar